# sqliteassethelper does not seem to create my table

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I followed the instructions in implementing SQLiteAssetHelper [here](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

I have a database that contains one table, tbl_items

Tried looking in the Android Device Monitor if it created my table, but it's not listed there. (or it's not supposed to be listed there? package name > file explorer > data > data > package name > databases)

Inside my class I have this code:

```
public class DBItems extends SQLiteAssetHelper{
    public DBItems(Context context) {
        super(context, "Items.db", null, 1);
    }


    public Cursor ItemInfo(String itemID){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor info = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE itemID = '" + itemID + "'", null);
        return info;
    }
}
```

And im trying to access it in my fragment:

```
DBItems dbItems = new DBItems(getActivity());
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Cursor info = dbItems.ItemInfo(String.valueOf(v.getTag())); //I've set a tag in my button

        while(info.moveToNext()){
            //display info
        }
```

Everytime I clicked the button, it just exits the app.
Did I miss something? or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `... This class provides developers with a simple way to ship their Android app with an existing SQLite database ...`

Comment: Have you include the database file in asset folder in your project?

Comment: and the correct path for an application database is `/data/data/your.package.name/your.db`

Comment: Yup, created an assets folder, created a folder name databases inside of it and copied my .db file there

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace/log?

Comment: Ooops sorry, it's a silly mistake, nvm, I didn't notice I was calling another class other than the DBItems.